# How to get object of a div present inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I am having 2 `html` files and one `IFrame` .

The structure is ,

[image]

I can able to get the object of an `outside.html` and `iframe`. But I cant get the object of an `inside.html`.

My inside.html will be,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/chat.css">
<title>Heart JSP page</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="messageArea" class="divBorder">

     Chat Interaction id is : Some value.

    </div>
    <div id="enterMessage" class="divBorder">
    Your message Area
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My `javascript` is

```
if($("#chatMessageArea").length){

    alert("outside.html Object is present !");

    if($("#ch"+intxnId).length){

        alert("IFrame Object is present !");

        if($("#ch"+intxnId).contents().find("#messageArea").length){
            alert("inside.html Object is present !");
        }else{
            alert("inside.html Object is not available !");
        }

    }else{
        alert("IFrame Object is not available !");
    }
}
else{
    alert("outside.html Object is not available  !");
}
```

Note :

`#chatMessageArea` - id of a div of the outside.html

`#chintxid`        - id of a iframe

`#messageArea`     - id of a div in the inside.html

Can anyone help to get the object of the inside.html.

Comment: Have you tested if `$("#ch"+intxnId).contents()` returns any value? By alerting of console logging.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes . I have checked `if     if($("#ch"+intxnId).contents()){
     alert("contents present");
    }else{
     alert("No contents present");
    }` . I got the `contents present` in the alert.

Comment: Try actually `alert`ing or console logging the contents. Perhaps you are getting something back but it's not actually filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by,

```
if($("#chatMessageArea").length){

    alert("chatMessageArea Object is present !");

    if($("#ch"+intxnId).length){

        if($("#ch"+intxnId).contents().find('body').find("#messageArea").length){

            alert("messageArea Object is present !");
        }else{
            alert("messageArea Object is not available !");
        }
    }else{
        alert("IFrame Object is not available !");
    }
}
else{
    alert("chatMessageArea Object  not available  !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('chintxid');
ifr.contentDocument.getElementById('messageArea').innerHTML = "reached!";
```

You need to get the iFrame id first and inside that the content of the one you need. Let me know if was this you were looking for..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am getting `contentDocument` is null or not an object error .

Comment: Can you echo `document.getElementById('messageArea');` from inside the iFrame?

Comment: Then the problem seems to be inside the iFrame. Can you post html or a live link?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.please see my updated question.I am using the `JSP` instead of the `HTML` page.

Comment: frame.contentDocument won't always work. Try frame.contentWindow.document (if your using Internet Explorer, I think)

Comment: Good point Ally. @KitePlayer, your inside.html looks good. What browser do you use?

Comment: How to share it.Can you please tell me the way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this helper function to get the document of the iframe

```
getFrameContentDocument = function(frame) {
   var doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
   return doc;
};
```

Then the code would be

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("ch" + intxid);
var iframeDoc = getFrameContentDocument(iframe);
// You can now get elements in this iframe 
var messageArea = iframeDoc.getElementById("messageArea");
```

Comment: Added Kite Player's slight edits, didn't know how to approve your edits sorry :/